# ¿Cómo establecer modelo "muchos a muchos" en MongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb, nosql, mongoose

Tengo una duda acerca de bases de datos no relacionales (mongodb).

Si tengo una colección de “libros” y otra de “usuarios”:

¿Cuál es la mejor manera para especificar cuáles son los libros favoritos del usuario?. **Considerando que puede tener grandes cantidades de libros favoritos**.

Se me ocurre que en los documentos de la colección “usuarios” se especifique un arreglo con los libros favoritos de cada usuario (haciendo referencia a los documentos de la colección “libros”).

Documento de colección “usuarios”:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c966"),
    "nombre": "Carlos López",
    "edad" : 22,
    "libros_favs": [
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c966”),
        (…)
    ] 
},
(…)
```

También podría ser crear una colección especifica para relacionar los datos, similar a lo anterior pero en una colección particular para representar los libros favoritos de cada usuario.

Documento de colección "user_libros_favs":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c2w13”),
    "id_user": ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c9"),
    "libros_favs": [
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4236"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcc323d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4236"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcc323d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4236"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcc323d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4236"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcc323d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4236"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcc323d360f0306c966"),
        ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c4353”),
        (…)
    ] 
},
(…)
```

En ambos casos tendría el problema de tener arreglos gigantes (growing data structure), lo cual pienso que es poco conveniente.

Otra opción sería crear una colección al estilo relacional “muchos a muchos”, donde en cada documento se especifique tanto el id del usuario como el id del libro.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c2w13”),
    "id_user": ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c5”),
    "id_libro”: ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0s3d9")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f030632w12”),
    "id_user": ObjectId("579c0dfcce3ds60f0306c9"),
    "id_libro”: ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0s2c9")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c0dfcce3d360f0306c2w13”),
    "id_user": ObjectId("529c0dfcce3d360f0306c1”),
    "id_libro”: ObjectId("579c0dfc3e3d360f0s2c0”)
},
(…)
```

Aquí se ve que colección sería demasiado grande, considerando una gran cantidad de usuarios agregando libros a favoritos.

Cuál sería la manera óptima para abarcar este problema en mongodb?

Comment: No soy un experto en Mongodb pero te puedo decir que la primera opción que has propuesto es la mejor: un documento con los datos del usuario y una lista con los ids de sus libros favoritos. Es cierto que tendrías arreglos gigantes pero eso no es tan malo. Las bases de datos "No-sql", como mongodb pretenden precisamente evitar cosas como las otras dos opciones que has dado (una colección específica para relacionar datos). Si quieres hacerlo de ese modo es mejor una base de datos relacional tradicional. Mongodb prentende que los datos se organicen de una manera más intuitiva sin tener que hacer

Comment: Yo tampoco soy ningún experto pero, con este tipo de bases de datos lo importante es no anidar demasiado. Yo también me decantaría por la primera opción, aunque habría que ver la opinión de algún experto en el tema.

Comment: En mi experiencia optaría por usar la relación muchos a muchos. Porque en las otras dos formas tu documento crecerá y cuando hagas consultas en donde solo necesites el nombre, email u otro dato del usuario obtendras todo el documento completo. Otro punto a tener en cuenta, es que los documentos de mongodb tienen una capacidad máxima de 16MB. En cambio con la relación de M:M puedes agregar un índice a tu id_user o id_libro y tus querys seran más rápidos. Considero que vas a encontrar muchas opinones divididas, **lo importante es que consideres como vas a leer la información y sobre eso decidas

Comment: Para mi la mejor forma es tener un documento para libros, otro para usuarios y otra tabla llamada no sé user_book donde tenga el id de ambos, el problema ahí es como se hace la consulta luego para saber por ejemplo del usuario X cuales son los libros que le gustan, en SQL es muy facil con un Join o con una consulta a 3 tablas pero aquí en mongo no tengo ni idea como se hace.

Comment: Yo me inclino mas por la tercer opción.