# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de modelar relaciones muchos a muchos en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Estoy desarrollando una api en node.js con express y para la persistencia de los datos estoy usando mongodb con mongoose. Actualmente tengo un problema en el modelado de colecciones y estaría necesitando ayuda.

Explico un poco cual es la idea para que se pueda entender la pregunta:

La api que estoy desarrollando es para múltiples empresas (varios usuarios de una empresa pueden consultar datos a esta api y dependiendo que usuario haga el request la api responderá unos datos u otros).

Cuando un usuario se crea una cuenta debe indicar a que empresa pertenece y que rol cumple dentro de esa empresa. (Dependiendo que empresa haya seleccionado se le mostraran unos roles y otros). Cada rol tiene permisos para consultar ciertos datos

Entonces hasta ahora tengo la entidad empresa, rol y usuario.

La pregunta es, que tipo de relación se recomienda para estos casos ? relaciones referenciadas o embebidas ? seria mala idea (en cuanto a rendimiento) meter las entidades "rol" y "usuario" dentro de la entidad "empresa" ? porque si vamos al caso, los roles y los usuarios son unicos en cada empresa.

Hasta ahora he generado las colecciones en mongoose tal que asi:

```
var Empresas = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String, required: true },
    employees: [{
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true },
        role: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Roles" },
    }],
});

var Roles = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId
    business_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Empresas" },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    permissions: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Permisos" }],
});

var Permisos = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Es la primera vez que estoy usando bases de datos nosql y se me hace muy difícil diagramar las entidades y relaciones, entiendo que el objetivo de las bases de datos nosql es mejorar el rendimiento de las consultas, dejando un poco de lado la redundancia por asi decirlo, también he leído que el hecho de usar relaciones embebidas o por referencias dependen mucho del tipo de aplicación que se este desarrollando, pero por lo general, que tipo de relación se recomienda ? realmente empeora el rendimiento el hecho de hacer referencias a otras entidades ?

Comment: mira en esta pagina te puede dar solución  [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21500/c%C3%B3mo-establecer-modelo-muchos-a-muchos-en-mongodb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo diseñaría así:

Colecciones mínimas:

- Empresas
- Roles
- Usuarios
- Permisos
- Acciones

Donde Acciones contendrá los ID de Empresas, Roles, Usuarios y Permisos y servirá para relacionar todo lo que un determinado usuario (que pertenece a una empresa, tiene un rol y permisos) puede hacer o no.

Por ejemplo:

```
Acciones: {
  empresa: '1',
  rol: '1',
  usuario: '1',
  permisos: ['1', '2']
}
```

Aquí supondremos que los números enteros son los ID's de las otras colecciones para **referenciarlas**

Con esta opción tu DB es más **flexible y escalable** en relación a agregar nuevos tipos de roles y acciones.

Nota que permisos es un array que contendrá ID's de la colección Permisos, para este atributo se está relacionando de "uno a muchos", ya que para el usuario 1 que pertenece a la empresa 1 y cuyo rol es 1, tiene los permisos 1 y 2. Esto es así porque ¿Qué pasa si existe un usuario que pertenezca a más de una empresa? ¿Cómo diferenciar los roles y permisos? este puede ser un modo.

Nota también que si un usuario puede tener N roles a la vez, entonces el atributo roles se convierte a un array de ID's al igual que permisos.

**¿Y por qué referenciados?** por performance, ya que en muchos contextos necesitarás cargar sólo la información del usuario como su nombre. Imagina que en tu colección Usuarios tuvieses embebido un montón de información, pero la mayoría de los casos sólo te interesa sacar su nombre para mostrarlo en el frontend, es un desperdicio de recursos.

"Pero puedo hacer el filtro en el find() para que me devuelva sólo el nombre", sí, *pero lo que muchos no saben es que cuando haces un find() con un filtro para los atributos, primero te obtiene el documento entero y después lo filtra*, entonces aunque lo filtres, te puede afectar. Claro que estoy hablando cuando es mucha información embebida, pero lo mejor es pensar en el performance siempre.

Comment: excelente! esto realmente me sirve muchas gracias!

Comment: @Oscar si te sirvió mucho, considera marcar esta respuesta como útil, incluso si te solucionó tu problema entonces como la respuesta correcta :o

Answer (score 1):

Usa referencias en lugar de documentos embebidos. La razón es simple:

> Si quieres cambiar datos sobre un rol o permiso, debes hacerlo para todos los documentos, significando consultas innecesarias.

Una buena pauta a seguir sobre cuándo usar referencias o embebidos es si un documento será compartido entre varios otros o si es **único del documento principal**. En este último caso es mejor embeberlo porque no te interesa trabajar con ellos a nivel de base de datos; en cambio, si serán compartidos es mejor trabajarlos como referencias porque cualquier cambio que se hagan en los documentos originales se verán reflejados en los otros.